# Unknown error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build

There are no errors & no warnings, I have done <kbd>Build Clean</kbd> is clean. I am running on my iPhnoe and <kbd>Development target</kbd> is equal. Despite of this I am facing this unknown error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quit and restart your XCode, Restarting xcode solves this issue sometimes

Comment: I quit Xcode at that time and started working on another project after few minutes I opened the project it gave the signal SIGABRT error. I can not decide whether the quieting Xcode might solve the problem or there might be a signal SIGABRT issue on backside.

Comment: This could be beacuse of memory issues. Try to Reset Content and Settings of simulator. Then try to run project

Comment: I am running on my iPhone, how can i reset my contents & setting?